# Change listener angle in FMOD

Tags: iphone, fmod

I have set up an event system in FMOD with 3D sound triggered when the listener is close to them. I want to be able to change the listener angle of the listener so that my entire sound landscape shifts the same amount of degrees as my listener rotates. Nice huh?

Is it possible? What would be the iPhone code for that? 
Would I pass something to the method set3DListenerAttributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, do you just want to rotate the listener in 3D space? If so you adjust the listener forward vector to point in the new direction.

** Based on your response **

FMOD works with a cartesian co-ordinate system, it has a unit length vector which points in the direction an object (or listener) is facing. I would recommend you do some reading on trigonometry to fully understand how to convert an angle (in degrees or radians) to a vector.

For your forward vector the equation is (if I remember correctly):
x = cos(angle)
z = sin(angle)
y = 0;

This assumes angle is in radians, to convert from degrees to radians:
radians = degrees * (180 / Pi)
where Pi is roughly 3.14159265

Comment: Thank you mr Block! You are a star!

Answer (score 0):

This was the code I used in the end:

```
float degree = 90;
float radians = (degree) * (M_PI/180);


float fx = cos(radians);
float fz = sin(radians);

forward.x = fx;
forward.z = fz;

listenerpos.x = lxPos * DISTANCEFACTOR;   
listenerpos.z = lyPos * DISTANCEFACTOR;


result = eventSystem->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos,&vel,&forward,NULL);
```